# Unable to install updates

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management

I am trying to install the regular updates on my Ubuntu 12.04 but for some reason I keep getting this error. Any Idea how I can resolve it?

[image: error]

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal first, then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and paste the output here.  CLI programs tend to be more verbose when they encounter a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the key for the qgis repo. Assuming you installed it using the repo found [here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download), just add the key, like this:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 997D3880
gpg --export --armor 997D3880 | sudo apt-key add -
```

You will then need to run update apt, and it should work.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it. Also I had to take @InkBlend advise as well. After executing your commands I also executed `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Np, I forgot to add the `apt-get update` part. The dist-upgrade isn't exactly necessary, since you are doing the same thing through the GUI when you run updates. I updated my answer in the hopes it will help someone else.